# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'x'

Tags: python-3.x

when the the last index on string has "x" or "X" (It is represent as 10) so if I have something like "1x", which mean 11 (1 + 10)

```
def main():
    s1 = "013162959x"
    partial_sums(s1)


def partial_sums(s1):
    lst =[]
    sum = 0    
    for i in range(len(s1)):
       if (i == len(s1) -1) and (s1[i] == "x" or "X"):
            sum = sum + int(s1[i]) + 10
        else:
            sum = sum + int(s1[i])
        lst.append(sum)
    print(lst)


main()
```

**I got an ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'x'**

the output should be [0, 1, 4, 5, 11, 13, 22, 27, 36, 46]

When the string contain No "X" value it work fine.

```
def main():
    s1 = "0131629592"  
    partial_sums(s1)

def partial_sums(s1):
    lst1 =[]
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(s1)):
        sum = sum + int(s1[i])
        lst1.append(sum)
    print(lst1)

main()
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This statement:

```
   if (i == len(s1) -1) and (s1[i] == "x" or "X"):
        sum = sum + int(s1[i]) + 10
```

still calls `int` on `s1[i]` even though `s1[i]` is `"x"`.  You simply want `sum += 10`.

However, note that `or` doesn't work the way you're using it.  To quote the docs, "The expression `x or y` first evaluates *x*; if *x* is true, its value is returned; otherwise, *y* is evaluated and the resulting value is returned."  IOW, `"a" == "b" or "c"` returns `"c"`, not False, and `"c"` evaluates as True.

Also, since `sum` is a really useful builtin, it's probably a bad idea to shadow it with a variable of your own with the same name.  `total` is often used instead.

Comment: Can I do this way? if (i == len(s1) -1) and ((s1[i] == "x") or (s1[i] == "X"))   or is there any better way?

Comment: @user1804925: that should work.  You could also do `s1[i].lower() == 'x'` or `s1[i] in ('x', 'X')` (I'd probably do the first one, myself.)